# Java Secure Random - AES Encryption

Tags: encryption, aes

I am new to AES encryption. I have created an Initialization Vector using the secure random required for AES encryption.

```
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    random.nextBytes(iv);
```

I want to display the iv on the UI so that if a user wants they can change it. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Some common encodings for expressing binary data as strings are base64 and hex.

Comment: Don't show the IV to the user and don't change it. Generate it once for every encryption and then store it together with encrypted data.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Thanks,
If I convert that to hex and then again retrieve it to generate the AES encrypted data. Then can I just get the bytes and use it or do I need to do any conversion ?

Comment: @rustyx Do you see any concern in displaying it to the user ?

Comment: @Neetu There is nothing wrong with the IV being publicly view-able or displayed.  There isn't really a reason to do it though.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Thanks. The requirement is to test few negative cases. Where the user can change the IV and decryption should fail.

Comment: @Neetu Decryption won't necessarily fail for an incorrect IV.  You should research authenticated modes and MACs.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Sure. I will read more on it.